# Looping through Table A and updating Table B Column C using PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

There's a table called `TableA` and another table called `TableB`

I need to copy values of the column `ValueC` in the table `TableB` to the column `ValueD` in table `TableA`. Both tables share a common column: `Table_id`

I tried using:

```
DECLARE 
   CURSOR c_App
   IS
     SELECT *
       from TableA
BEGIN 
   for i in c_App
   LOOP
     select ValueD from TableB where Table_id = c_App.Table_id;
   END LOOP;
   update TableA set ValueC = ValueD  where Table_id = c_App.Table_id
END;
```

However, I got an error in SQL developer:

> ```
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:
>
>    begin function package pragma procedure subtype type use
>    <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> form
>    current cursor
> 06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
> *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
> *Action:
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

Is there an easier way? I'm relatively new to PL/SQL and while I feel a join could be an easier alternative.

Comment: you are missing a semicolon after the update.

Comment: @OldProgrammer i commented out the update statement, and i still get the same error

Comment: Missing semicolon after cursor declaration as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to use procedural processing in your situation. You could accomplish this by using [merge](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9016.htm#i2081218) statement:

```
merge 
 into tableA ta
using TableB tb
   on (ta.table_id = tb.table_id)
when matched
then update 
        set ta.valueD = tb.valueC
```

Comment: i got `SQL Error: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables
30926. 00000 -  "unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables"
*Cause:    A stable set of rows could not be got because of large dml
           activity or a non-deterministic where clause.
*Action:   Remove any non-deterministic where clauses and reissue the dml.`

Comment: @LaneLane That error indicates that you have duplicates in the `TableB` - table you are getting data from, specifically in the `table_id` column and oracle wont be able to decide what `valueC` to choose when there two or more identical `table_id` columns. So the question arises, when there are two records `table_id: 1, valueC 1` and `table_id:1, ValueC 2`, which one to choose?

Comment: you're spot on! in `TableB`, `valueC 1` and `valueC 2` are always unique and i would like them to be stored in column `valueD` in this format `valueC1</br>valueC2</br>` instead of a singular value

Comment: @LaneLane column `ValueC` is involved in the update process and cannot be used for unique row identification.